# Adding a handler to all clients created via IHttpClientFactory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

Is there a way to add a handler to all clients created by the IHttpClientFactory?

I know you can do the following on named clients:

```
services.AddHttpClient("named", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("TODO");
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
    {
        NoCache = true,
        NoStore = true,
        MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0),
        MustRevalidate = true
    };
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
});
```

But I don't want to use named clients.

I just want to add a handler to all clients that are given back to me via:

```
clientFactory.CreateClient();
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you use `CreateClient` with no parameters, you [implicitly](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/HttpClientFactoryExtensions.cs#L25) request a named client, where the name is [`Options.DefaultName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.options.defaultname) (`string.Empty`).

To affect this *default* instance, specify `Options.DefaultName` when calling `AddHttpClient`:

```
services.AddHttpClient(Options.DefaultName, c =>
{
    // ...
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    // ...
});
```

The [API docs for `AddHttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient) states the following:

> Use [DefaultName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.options.defaultname) as the name to configure the default client.