# Disable SSL certificate verification in default injected IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

In Startup.cs I inject an `IHttpClientFactory` service:

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

I can then create a new `HttpClient` through

```
public MyClass(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IOptions<MyClassOptions> options)
{
    _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    // ...
}
```

`MyClass` does some API access; the base URL is passed in the `options` object.

For testing I set up a dummy instance of the API, which uses a self-signed SSL certificate. Unfortunately, this certificate is (correctly) recognized as invalid:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

How can I disable certificate verification at the factory layer, i.e. directly in the `ConfigureServices` method?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283898/ignore-ssl-connection-errors-via-ihttpclientfactory), but it seemed to use some custom `HttpClient` implementation (?), while I want to target the default one. The following does not work (DI picks the wrong constructor and subsequently fails):

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496011/8528014) suggests to supply a name for the configured `HttpClient`, but it passes some magic string, which I would like to avoid (`MyClass` is located in a class library designed to be also used by others). Passing no name does not work either, since `AddHttpClient` then merely returns an `IServiceCollection` object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out now. We can apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57235906/8528014) to modify the primary `HttpMessageHandler` of the default `HttpClient`:

```
services.AddHttpClient(Options.DefaultName, c =>
{
    // ...
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    return new HttpClientHandler
    {
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (httpRequestMessage, cert, certChain, policyErrors) => true
    };
});
```

This will yield `HttpClient` objects with disabled SSL verification, whenever the default `IHttpClientFactory` is injected.